# efficient solution for reshaping the dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe, time-complexity

I have a dataframe like

```
id col1 col2 col3 ......col25
1 a b c d ...........
2 d e f NA ........
3 a NA NA NA .......
```

What I want is:

```
id start end
1 a b
1 b c
1 c d
2 d e
2 e f

for names, row in data_final.iterrows():
    for i in range(0,26):
        try:
            x = pd.Series([row["id"],row[i], row[i+1]],index=['id', 'start','end'])
            df1 = df1.append(x, ignore_index = True)
        except:
            break
```

This works but it is definitely is not the best solution as its time complexity is too high.
I need a better and efficient solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way could be to [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) to remove missing values, `groupby` and `zip` to aggregate each elements with the succeeding one. The we just need to flatten the result with [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) and create a dataframe:

```
from itertools import chain
l = [list(zip(v.values[:-1], v.values[1:])) for _,v in df.stack().groupby(level=0)]
pd.DataFrame(chain.from_iterable(l), columns=['start', 'end'])

  start end
0     a   b
1     b   c
2     c   d
3     d   e
4     e   f
```

Comment: But the ID column is missing in this. In my actual data frame, my ID's are strings. Which I want to be in the ID column after transformation.